# addin data to firestore database using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add an array of users as a collection to fire-store database here is my code and i think its suppose to be working but i get nothing in the firestore databse collections  so what exactly should i do can anyone help me with this??

```
import { addDoc ,  collection , setDoc , doc , getDocs} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "./config";

 const Users = [
    {
      userId: "XF9EvlJQZHfZEClM23Bd39A7gai1",
      username: "John",
      fullName: "John John",
      emailAddress: "John@gmail.com",
      dateCreated: Date.now(),
    },
    {
      userId: "XF9EvlJQZHfZEClM23Bd39A7gai1",
      username: "John",
      fullName: "John John",
      emailAddress: "John@gmail.com",
      dateCreated: Date.now(),
    }]

Users.forEach(async (user) => {
     try {
      const docRef = await addDoc (collection(db , "users" , user.userId) ,{
        userId: user.userId,
        username: user.username,
        fullName: user.fullName,
        emailAddress: user.emailAddress,
        dateCreated: user.dateCreated,
      })
      console.log("Document written with ID : ",docRef.id)
     } catch(err){
      console. Error("Error adding document ",err)
     }
 })
```

here is my firestore database :

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";



const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};


export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const storage = getStorage();
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `async`/`await` within a `forEach()` loop, see "[JavaScript: async/await with forEach()](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404)" and "[Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)".

You can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
const Users = [
  {
    userId: "XF9EvlJQZHfZEClM23Bd39A7gai1",
    username: "John",
    fullName: "John John",
    emailAddress: "John@gmail.com",
    dateCreated: Date.now(),
  },
  {
    userId: "XF9EvlJQZHfZEClM23Bd39A7gai1",
    username: "John",
    fullName: "John John",
    emailAddress: "John@gmail.com",
    dateCreated: Date.now(),
  }]

try {
  const promises = [];
  Users.forEach((user) => {
    promises.push(
      setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.userId),
        {
          userId: user.userId,
          username: user.username,
          fullName: user.fullName,
          emailAddress: user.emailAddress,
          dateCreated: user.dateCreated,
        })
    );
  });

  await Promise.all(promises);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

Comment: i tried man  I got nothing either , thanks

Comment: Do you get an error? Are there sole security rules that could prevent the writes?

Comment: Also note that similarly to export `const db = getFirestore(app);` you should do `export const auth = getAuth(app);` and the same for Storage.

Comment: no there isn't any errors

Comment: See the update to my code

Comment: Nope, that did not work either , there is something wrong with firestore am pretty sure that the code is okay

Comment: 've deleted the whole app and still got nothing

Comment: I found the solution , I wrapped the whole database inside a function and called it inside the firebase config  file and also changed the rules of fire-store to allow read and write and finally this worked for me, thank  you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think the path that you are giving it to set new users to the collection is not getting the id of the user so its not adding the doc

```
addDoc(collection(db, "users", user.userId)
```

Do this and let firebase gives them a unique id

```
addDoc(collection(db, "users")
```

or could be also what Renaud said, maybe you havent set the rules to allow you to edit the database.

Comment: i changed the rules to allow read and write if true and still got nothing